# Solve Normal form Nash eq. (pure and mixed), especially the probabilities

Tags: probability, game-theory, economics, nash-equilibrium

can someone please help me to solve this question:

Consider the normal form game:

[image: Normal form game]

i) For Player 1 the strategy B is strictly dominated by C.

ii) For Player 2 the strategy E is strictly dominated by F.

iii) The game has 2 Nash eq. in pure strategies and further equilibrium in mixed strategies. In this third eq. player 1 chooses between A,B, and C according to the probabilities:

σA= __________, σB= ___________, σC= _____________.

and player 2 chooses between D,E and F according to the probabilities:

σD= __________, σE= ___________, σF _____________.

It would be nice if someone of you can help me to find the solution for the probabilities (Step iii), with a quick explanation. I only can solve a 2x2 matrix but have never done this for a 3x3 matrix.

And are the solutions for i) and ii) correct?

Thanks for helping me!

Comment: Preferred to have the image displayed directly into the query.  I placed an `!` before the image reference.  You can read more about inserting images into a query [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/formatting).  Going forward, with your future mathSE queries, you can use [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) to (also) insert tables, as well as math in your queries.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the numbers in the bimatrix are the *payoffs* to the players (as opposed to *penalties* on them), I believe your answers i) and ii) have the dominance the wrong way round.  Each payoff to player $1$ in strategy B is strictly *larger* than the corresponding payoff in strategy C, so it's B that strictly dominates C, not the other way round.

Likewise, each payoff to player $2$ in strategy E is strictly larger than the corresponding payoff in strategy F, so E strictly dominates F.

**Hint for solving iii):**

Since strategy C is strictly dominated by strategy B for player $1$ it cannot appear with positive probability in any Nash equilibrium.  Likewise, strategy F for player $2$ cannot appear with positive probability in any Nash equilibrium.   You can therefore ignore those strategies entirely and obtain the Nash equilibria of the original $3\times3$ game by finding the Nash equilibria of the $2\times2$ game with bimatrix:
\begin{array}{||c|c|}
\hline
&\text{D}&\text{E}\\
\hline
\text{A}&6,12&4,8\\
\hline
\text{B}&4,8&8,16\\
\hline
\end{array}

Comment: Thank you, this answer helps me a lot to understand finding the dominant strategies. I find it always confusing to get the right way and in sum the right solution. 

Regarding to hint iii) 
I also thought that it doesn't make sense to calculate any right solution for the σC and as well for σF. With the 2x2 matrix it possible to find the right probability value.